# Can I transfer a file larger than 4096 MB anywhere in the world using uTorrent safely and securely?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, data-transfer, bittorrent

I want to send a file larger than 4096 Megabytes or 4 Gigabytes to anywhere in the world. It's a huge file.

I know I can seed the file using uTorrent. And the person receiving the file can have a link through email and download the file from there.

Can I use uTorrent a bittorrent client program to do this? Is it safe and secured? If not, can I encrypt the file using AES encryption and send the person the decryption key in secured VPN Gmail would that be okay? Is there any other free software that does encryption and I can be able to send a link to the receiving end and the same program is used to download the file by decrypting it using the link send through VPN Gmail exactly like uTorrent but this time safely and securely without doing two things separately? Why I ask this question is that I read somewhere that uTorrent file transfer through a hyperlink is not safe. Is that true?

I have created a long workout video of mine for my friend to see in a different country. So this question.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! You ask a lot of questions in this post, most of which are off-topic here (this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc.) I assume you're looking for a file-transfer software (for which OS?). Torrents are if you want to *spread* something to multiple recipients and thus wouldn't be a good fit for this.

Comment: If you have space on some cloud storage: encrypt the file, upload it, and send your friend the link plus the decryption key via separate channels (e.g. the link by mail, the key with a messenger). Else, burn it on a DVD and send it by snail mail.

Comment: You can also use sftp, or anything over the tor network.

Answer (score 1):

The least private is to upload to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) and set the video private. then you can share the link. But if anyone guesses the link they **will** be able to see the video!

The easies but not very private is to share via [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) etc.. That way only your Provider (google or Dropbox etc.) can see the video

If your only concern is security and not cencorship use:

### Cloud Providers - Mega.nz

This wont help you if there is an issue with spies or cencorship but it is easy and can be relatively secure. The uploader gets an account (the downloader can too if you want to be a little more secure) then encrypt the file with something like [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) (create a container a little bigger than your file and send the password via email using [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) encryption) or just encrypt the file directly with [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy). Then upload to [mega](https://mega.nz/) and share with your friend. If he has an account just add him if not you can share via link.

If your only concern is that only your friend sees the video but you aren't to scared by hackers then just share with [mega](https://mega.nz/) without the added encryption. As long as both of you have an account on mega then the file should stay encrypted until it is on your friends computer.

If your concern is security **and** avoiding censorship and you don't mind a slow up-/download speed you could take a look at

### Onion Share

It tunnels your traffic for the up-/download through [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/). One of you needs to get [OnionShare](https://onionshare.org/) and one needs the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/). Then the one with OnionShare selects if he wants to upload or download and shares the link with the other, who can then open it in Tor browser (not any ordinary browser). Then one uploads the file and the other one can download.

This may take a while and both PCs need to stay on!

OnionShare is really only meant to be used if you have great security concerns or if there is an issue with censorship. Thats why many jounylists use it (e.g. Edward Snowden shared some data with Glenn Greenwald). So if you don't need the security **and** avoid cencorship you might want to look for something else.